# Configuração do .htaccess para acessar diversos arquivos PHP dentro de uma mesma pasta

Tags: php, apache

Estou me batendo desde ontem com a configuração do meu `.htaccess`, minha URL original está assim (2 é o numero da página):

```
www.example.com/categoria/produtos/2
```

`Categoria` é uma pasta dentro do meu `public_html` e `produtos` fica dentro da mesma.

Até ai tudo bem, só que dentro de `categoria`, tenho vários outros arquivos `.php`.

Atualmente meu `.htaccess` esta assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ produto.php?page=$1
```

Resumindo, para todas as paginas dentro do meu `categoria`, estão sendo redirecionadas para `produto.php` e as páginas não passam, sempre o resultado fica no mesmo!

**A estrutura do código esta assim:**

```
  $url = $_GET['page']; //Pegando página selecionada na URL
  $dados = explode('/', $url);
  $dir = $dados[0]; 
  $page = $dados[1]; 

  if(empty($_GET['page'])){
    $page=1;
  }
  if($page >= '1'){
    $page = $page;
  }
  else{
    $page= '1';
  }
```

E na paginação esta assim:

```
echo "<li><a href='/categoria/produto.php/".($page+1)."'>NEXT</a></li>";
```

Comment: Adiciona outra condição, para as categorias.

Comment: Recomendo um htaccess com `RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L]` e deixar o sistema rotear a URL. Assim fica mais fácil você gerenciar as rotas.

Comment: [Implementando URL amigáveis com roteamento](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95310/url-amigavel-dinamica/98403?noredirect=1#comment200509_98403)

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**.HTACCESS**</sub>

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L]
```

<sub>**ROTA**</sub>

```
// www.meusite.com/categoria/produtos/2 -> carros/novos
$url = ltrim( parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , PHP_URL_PATH ) , '/' );

$router= explode( '/' , $url );
$router[0] // categoria
$router[1] // produtos
$router[2] // 2
```

---

Toda informação da sua URL vai estar no array `router`.
Você decide como verificar os indices de `$router[X]`.

Há várias formas de rotear a URL, essa é a mais simples, porém, **mantém a lógica no PHP**, sendo mais fácil incluir, alterar ou remover qualquer categoria.

Seu HTACCESS vai aceitar qualquer URL, mas cabe ao PHP validar e decidir o `controller` responsável por cada segmento da rua rota...

> <sub>www.domain.com/contato
>
>   www.domain.com/categoria
>
>   www.domain.com/categoria/busca
>
>   www.domain.com/categoria/produtos
>
>   www.domain.com/categoria/produtos/2
>
>   ... **N combinações**</sub>

Answer (score 0):

pra url

```
http://www.meusite.com/categoria/produtos/556
```

tenta isso

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(categoria/produtos/[0-9]+)$ produto.php?page=$1
```

ou

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+/[a-z]+/[0-9]+)$ produto.php?page=$1
```

dai no php produto.php

```
<?php  
$url = $_GET['page']; //Pegando página selecionada na URL  
$dados = explode('/', $url);  
$dir = $dados[0];  
$subdir = $dados[1];  
$page = $dados[2];  

if(empty($_GET['page'])) {  
$page = 1;

} else if ($page >= '1') {  
$page = $page;  

} else {  
$page= '1';  

}
```

esse site é bom pra simular rewrite .htaccess
http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Nada, Retorna Internal Server Error ... Só para reforçar, meu .htaccess coloquei dentro do categoria, para aplicar as config para paginas dentro desta pasta, correto? ... Sobre o nginx, utilizo um site de hospedagem, ai complica rsrs ..

Comment: William, não foi .. o que acontece, todas as paginas da categoria então listando o conteudo da minha index.php que esta dentro da public_html ...

Comment: hummmm cara tenta mais essa aqui, coloca esse .htaccess dentro da pasta categoria `RewriteRule ^(produtos/[0-9]+)$ produto.php?page=$1` isso pega somente as url digitadas com "produtos/[0-9]+" depois de categoria.

Comment: Ainda não William, agora ele mostra só os produtos.php, só que não passa a página. rsrs

Comment: editei a minha resposta, testei aqui e funcionou, .htaccess é foda mesmo kkk

Answer (score 0):

Antes de responder a pergunta em si, um detalhe importante que pode causar muita confusão nos seus testes: *não se esqueça de definir o caminho base!*

Isso pode ser feito no .htaccess, mas a forma mais simples é fazer pelo html mesmo:

```
<!-- inclua isso no "head" do html -->
<base href="http://a_url_do_seu_site.com/" />
```

Assim, principalmente quando se trabalha com muitas pastas e subpastas, arquivos com seções e subseções, não se perde o início absoluto da navegação para referência de todos os links.

**No seu caso**, se "categorias" for sempre a base, você poderia fazer isso:

```
<!-- inclua isso no "head" do html -->
<base href="http://www.meusite.com/categoria/" />
```

E todo o retorno das urls amigáveis começariam com "produto/página", ignorando o categorias, que seria sua "home", por assim dizer.

Voltando ao seu problema, esse tipo de situação é o que a gente chama de "múltiplas entradas", quando há mais de um arquivo .php para chamar, em vez de apenas um index.php. Neste caso, o .htaccess pode ser configurado de duas formas.

**Primeira Opção**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1
```

Aqui não muda nada em relação ao caso de entrada única, mas os arquivos existentes também são chamados pela query string "amigável". Para isso, basta convencionar que o primeiro parâmetro (no seu caso) é uma pasta, e o segundo é o nome do arquivo. Por exemplo:

```
www.meusite.com/categoria/produtos/2
```

extraindo a query srtring:

```
$qs = explode("/", ltrim($_GET['p'], "/"));

$caminho = $qs[0];
$arquivo = $qs[1].".php";
$parametro = $qs[2];
// e assim sucessivamente...
```

O mais importante nesse método é você entender que precisa elaborar uma forma de padronizar os endereços e a estrutura de pastas e arquivos do seu projeto. É mais fácil (e benéfico em diversos sentidos) você planejar bem o projeto, do que ficar queimando fósforo com o .htaccess.

**Segunda Opção (não recomendo, mas existe)**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

O que muda, é que agora você pode passar caminhos completos, e o último parâmetro (sem barra) será o nome do arquivo php. Acho que nem preciso dizer que não há vantagens nessa abordagem no seu caso, principalmente porque ela dificulta a passagem de query strings.

Para finalizar, eu vejo algo que poderia ser mudado no seu código da paginação, que está assim:

```
if(empty($_GET['page'])){ 
    $page=1;              
}                         
if($page >= '1'){
    $page = $page;
} else {
    $page= '1';
}
```

Quando seria mais interessante fazer isso:

```
$page = 1;                   // por padrão, page é sempre 1
$dir  = "produtos";          // outro padrão, por exemplo
if (!empty($_GET['page'])) { // todo o resto só faz sentido se houver dados
    $dados = explode("/", ltrim($_GET['pages'], "/"));   
    $dir  = $dados[0];
    $page = empty($dados[1]) ? 1 : $dados[1]; // só por garantia...
}
```