# Como usar URLs diferentes e pegar informações delas

Tags: php, url

Eu tenho um banco de dados com o seguinte

```
ID Nome
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

Eu gostaria que ao acessar `www.example.com/perfil.php` pegue todas as informações e imprima na tela, porem ao acessar `www.example.com/2/B` ou `www.example.com/1/A` pegue apenas estas informações e imprima na tela.

Comment: o termo técnico é "URL Rewrite" ou "Reescrita de URL". Um termo popular é "URL amigável" ou "URL açucarada". Pesquise por esses termos e entenderá o que fazer.

Comment: Fiz algumas explicações sobre HTACCES em outras questões que podem servir como base: [Exemplo 1](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28076/13412), [Exemplo 2](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27535/13412), [Exemplo 3](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34108/13412)

Comment: [Implementando URL amigáveis com roteamento](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95310/url-amigavel-dinamica/98403?noredirect=1#comment200509_98403)

Answer (score 0):

Uma explicação bem completa pode ser encontrada aqui

http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Apache-22-Introducao-ao-modulo-mod-rewrite?pagina=1

Corrigindo a sua pergunta pelo que entendi você não precisa que seja passado os dois valores apenas um seria o suficiente. Por exemplo.
www.site.com/2 -> Retornaria todas as informações do usuário de nome B
ou www.site.com/B também recuperaria as informações do mesmo usuário correto?

Porque se for passado um número você faria uma busca baseada em Identificador e caso seja passado um Alfa( letras e números) você recuperaria o perfil pelo nome de usuário.

Busca no Google Rewrite_mod  que é um modulo do apache.

Comment: Por exemplo, caso eu acesse www.site.com/perfil.php vai imprimir "1 A", eu quero que faça o mesmo processo porem a url seria www.site.com/1/A, e essa url seria diferente a cada dado diferente.

Comment: Então você necessita fazer um mapeamento da url para que seja repassado para o arquivo necessário;

Comment: Poderia me passar uma matéria sobre isso ??

Comment: No artigo que passei acima tem toda a explicação que você precisa para utilização.